# How to Add an Extra Label on x-axis without Data in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data frame is:

year_period portal_use_repeat      n percent
                        
1 jan15       Yes                41707    10.2
2 jul15       Yes                87504    10.6
3 jan16       Yes                91165    11.1
4 jul16       Yes                92672    11.4
5 jul17       Yes               100826    12.8

As can be noticed from data above, jan17 is missing because there is no data. I want to plot the percent participants by year_period but would like to add an empty jan17 label to the x-axis so that the space between jul16 and jul17 is the same as the space between jul15 and jul16

Plot: [current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWKE9.png)

This is the code for the plot:

```
p <- ggplot(data=graphdata, aes(x=year_period, y=percent, group=portal_use_repeat, color=portal_use_repeat)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=portal_use_repeat))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=portal_use_repeat), size=3)+
  xlab("Survey Year/Period")+
  ylab("% of participants")+  
  labs(title ="Online Repeat Prescription use")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("2015 Jan", "2015 Jul", "2016 Jan", "2016 Jul", "2017 Jul", limits =rev(jan17)))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(5, 15))+
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Next time if You want to show your data use `dput(your_data)`, and paste the result here between ``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want to add an empty label to x-axis, use `limits` in `scale_x_discrete()`.

```
ggplot(data=graphdata, aes(x=factor(year_period,level = c('jan15','jul15','jan16','jul16','jul17')), y=percent, group=portal_use_repeat, color=portal_use_repeat)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=portal_use_repeat))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=portal_use_repeat), size=3)+
  xlab("Survey Year/Period")+
  ylab("% of participants")+  
  labs(title ="Online Repeat Prescription use") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c('jan15','jul15','jan16','jul16', 'jan17', 'jul17'),labels = c("2015 Jan", "2015 Jul", "2016 Jan", "2016 Jul", "2017 Jan", "2017 Jul")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(5, 15))+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]